# Boot error: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65

Tags: boot, odin, error

On boot i get error message like this:

```
integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011: a92902398e16c49778cd90f99e4f9ae17c55af53'
integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011: 13adbf4309bd82709c8cd54f316ed522988a1bd4'
integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
integrity: Error adding keys to platform keyring UEFI:db
integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:MokListRT (MOKvar table)
integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority: ad91990bc22ab1f517048c23b6655a268e345a63'
```

after no error i don't get and can use my laptop normally, but what is mean this error?

Answer (score 0):

Often those are OEM certificates that are not valid anymore. Usually used for BIOS or firmware upgrades or some other crap. On my laptop I have two that fails to load, issuer CN=ABO and CN=DisablePW.

You can check which certificate it is. First get list

`dmesg | grep integrity`

Count in order which fails to load, then type

`mokutil --db | grep Issuer:`

Comment: Ueah, i see 3 certificate. But, how i can update it?

Comment: You can only try to update bios. There is no other way.